# How to make value in ascending order in the mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, select-query

I want this type of output to fetch task_name from database like in this format

```
Task 10 Task 2 Task 3 Task 5........
```

My Query is

```
 SELECT task_name, section_name, ref_student_id
 FROM scores
 WHERE ref_student_id = '".$studentid."'
    AND section_name = 'sm1'
 GROUP BY task_name
```

So I want to output like this..

```
 Task 2 Task 3 Task 5 Task 10........
```

Comment: can you post the real task name? or the schema? auto_increment ids and dates can help :D

Comment: Here is my database record............................................   task_name  section_name  ref_student_id
 Task10    sm1    1
 Task2    sm1    1
 Task3    sm1    1
 Task3    sm1    1
 Task3    sm1    1
 Task4    sm1    1
 Task4    sm1    1
 Task5    sm1    1
 Task6    sm1    1
 Task7    sm1    1
 Task7    sm1    1
 Task7    sm1    1
 Task8    sm1    1
 Task9    sm1    1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
"SELECT task_name, section_name, ref_student_id
 FROM scores
WHERE ref_student_id = '1'
AND section_name = 'sm1'
GROUP BY task_name
ORDER BY cast( SUBSTRING( task_name, 5 ) AS unsigned ) ASC"
```

Comment: After use this i get the output like                                           Task 3
Task 4
Task 6
Task 8
Task 2
Task 5                                                                      Still not work in my code.. please help me.Thanks

Comment: Here is my database record....                                           task_name  section_name  ref_student_id
 Task10    sm1    1
 Task2    sm1    1
 Task3    sm1    1
 Task3    sm1    1
 Task3    sm1    1
 Task4    sm1    1
 Task4    sm1    1
 Task5    sm1    1
 Task6    sm1    1
 Task7    sm1    1
 Task7    sm1    1
 Task7    sm1    1
 Task8    sm1    1
 Task9    sm1    1

Comment: datatype is varchar(255) of task_name

Comment: @NishantPatel i have changed query, please try this new query

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
SELECT task_name, section_name, ref_student_id
FROM scores
WHERE ref_student_id = '".$studentid."'
AND section_name = 'sm1'
ORDER BY ltrim(task_name) ASC          //order by should come for ordering....
GROUP BY task_name
```

instead of

```
SELECT task_name, section_name, ref_student_id
FROM scores
WHERE ref_student_id = '".$studentid."'
AND section_name = 'sm1'
GROUP BY task_name
```

Comment: Send the error using your code....the error is ....#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY task_name LIMIT 0, 30' at line 6

Answer (score 0):

```
"select task_name,section_name,ref_student_id from scores where ref_student_id = '".$studentid."' and section_name = 'sm1' GROUP BY task_name order by task_name ASC "
```

Order by Ascending